# How To Pass "Complete Action Using" Dialog Box In My Browser?

Tags: android, android-browser

I have a webview.

Code in my Activity:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    WebViewClient viewClient = new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url)); 

            startActivity(intent); 
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }
    };

    webView.setWebViewClient(viewClient);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }
```

Code in Layout:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

But when I click to a link or button in it, a dialog box appearing and saying "complete action using". I want to discard this dialog box and set default my app in my app. How can I do this programmatically?